# FastReport,Delphi XE7 - How to use internal and external Datasets simultaneously

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have report for Invoices. The thing is I have to show the report for preview before I save it to the database. For that I have all data stored in TVirtualTables which I'm passing by TfrxDBDatasets to FastReport. But after saving I want to get all data needed directly from Database. For that I have internal connection and datasets. How to switch between those datasets?

It means report has to use data from TfrxDBDatasets passed to it from Delphi application OR based on a some condition get all data needed directly from database internally in a FastReport report (without using TfrxDBDatasets passed from application).

Answer (score 1):

You could define another report (the same in fact with database tables defined) and load it at runtime

**clear report**

```
procedure Clear;
```

**load another report**

```
function LoadFromFile( const FileName: String ; ExceptionIfNotFound:

Boolean = False): Boolean;
```

Is this a possibility?

Comment: Report for a Invoice is rather complicated stuff I'd rather not double my work if I don't have to.

Comment: You could make a copy of the exact same report file and open it in the designer. Then assign the datasets and save it. You need to maintain both files, though...

Answer (score 1):

You have few aproaches there, 
Either just change .Data / .DataSource property of TfrxDBDataset
to something other than TVirtualTable 
or 
Assign Data from database to TVirtualTable:

```
FDQueryThis.Data := FDQueryOther.Data;
```

It's FireDac example but i believe Devart has .Assign method to acheve this:

```
VirtualTable1.Assign(UniQuery1);
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for response, but it is still manipulation on a Delphi application side. I needed solution for doing it on a FastReport side. That report is to be used by another program which doesn't know anything about datasets, fileds etc. It will knew some ID and a connection string for database. Maybe my question was not quite specific.

Comment: Well actually You didn't put that information in Your original question :) In that case i'd use FastReport built in database controls.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response. I decided to try do it myself. And I came up with that solution:
On a Delphi form place components: 
    TfrxADOComponents, TfrxDBDataset (set property "Dataset" to your table or query), TfsScript, TfsPascal.

code for two buttons (one for getting data from TfrxDBDataset and second getting data internal in FastReport script):

```
procedure TForm2.BtnFromVirtualTablesClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frxReport1.PreviewOptions.Maximized := true;
  frxReport1.PreviewOptions.Modal := true;
  frxReport1.LoadFromFile('d:\fastrep\testdanychazaVirtual.fr3');
  frxReport1.Variables['id']:='''0''';
  frxReport1.Variables['ConnStr']:='''''';

  frxReport1.PrepareReport();
  frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport();
end;

procedure TForm2.BtnFromDatabaseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frxReport1.PreviewOptions.Maximized := true;
  frxReport1.PreviewOptions.Modal := true;
  frxReport1.LoadFromFile('d:\fastrep\testVirtual.fr3');
  frxReport1.Variables['id']:='''1''';
  frxReport1.Variables['ConnStr']:=''''+
  'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog='+MSConnection.Database+';'+
    'Data Source='+MSConnection.Server+';User Id='+MSConnection.Username+
    ';Password='+MSConnection.Password+'''';
  frxReport1.PrepareReport();
  frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport();
end;
```

Now in FastReport designer on a sheet "Data" we need two components: ADODatabase and ADOQuery. To get all needed columns for that ADOQuery you have to set proper connection to database and open the Query. When fastreport get all columns needed - clear ADODatabase1.DatabaseName property and ADOQuery1.Database property. Those properties should be filled in a script in event "frxReport1OnStartReport". If not - there be an error about not found connection to database.

We need also two variables ID, ConnStr in our report (add them in menu Report->Variables).

Here is FastReport Pascal script:

```
procedure frxReport1OnStartReport(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin             
 if <ID><>'0' then                              
 begin
   ADODatabase1.databaseName:=<ConnStr>;
   ADODatabase1.connected:=true;
   ADOQuery1.database:=ADODatabase1;                                    
   ADOQuery1.open;  
   masterData1.dataset:=ADOQuery1;    
   memo1.memo.text:='[ADOQuery1."id"]';
   memo2.memo.text:='[ADOQuery1."name"]';
  end;
end;

begin

end.
```

On a report add master band and place two Memos on it and connect them to table which is linked to TfrxDBDataset - it will be default setting.

With that solution you can use FastReport *.fr3 file in any program you make. You just need get some ID and connection string to it. Or pass datasets with filled with data it needs.